# Why does cuda_free have such a high overhead? (is it due to zeroing?)

Tags: cuda, profiling

I observe cudaFree operation takes unacceptably long time to operate it. To verify it, I wrote a simple micro benchmark code to test cudaFree overhead. It shows the similar trend.

first step: `cudaMallocManaged`
It doesn't take that long time. Actually it is less than 1ms just only for cudaMallocManaged.

second step: `init`
To initialize malloced memory region, init function is called. And it also doesn't take less than 1ms.

third step: `cudaFree`
Now, the overhead appears. **It takes a lot of time.** One more things is **bigger gets the memory size, Longer it takes.** (beautifully linearly)

**Question is "Why does cudaFree have such a huge overhead? Does it fill whole memory region with zero for security issue? Or any other critical path it walks through?"**

Here is the code and the measured result.
Thank you in advance :) !!!

```
   10 int getMilliCount(){
   11   timeb tb;
   12   ftime(&tb);
   13   int nCount = tb.millitm + (tb.time & 0xfffff) * 1000;
   14   return nCount;
   15 }
   16
   17 int getTimeDiff(int baseTime){
   18   int diff = getMilliCount() - baseTime;
   19   return diff;
   20 }
   21
   22 __global__ void init(int* x, size_t bytes_){
   23   int num_ = bytes_/sizeof(int);
   24   for (int i=0; i<num_; i++){
   25     x[i] = i;
   26   }
   27 }
   28
   29 int main(){
   30   printf("sizeof(size_t): %zu\n", sizeof(size_t));
   31   printf("sizeof(unsigned int): %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
   32   printf("sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(int));
   33   printf("sizeof(long): %zu\n", sizeof(long));
   34
   35   std::ofstream myfile;
   36   myfile.open("output3.csv");
   37   myfile<<"operation, num_bytes, start, end, duration\n";
   38   int baseTime = getMilliCount();
   39   int* dptr;
   40   int ts1 = 0;
   41   int ts2 = 0;
   42   size_t KB = 1024; // start from 1KB
   43   int num_trial_ = 1;
   44   for (int j=10; j<25; j++){
   45     size_t num_bytes_ = KB<<j;
   46     for (int i=0; i<num_trial_; i++){
   47       // measuring cudaMallocManaged
   48       ts1 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
>> 49       cudaMallocManaged((void**)&dptr, num_bytes_);
   50       ts2 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
   51       myfile<<"cudaMallocManaged, "<<num_bytes_/(1024*1024)<<","<<ts1<<","<<ts2<<","<<ts2-ts1<<"\n";
   52       //printf("cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:%zuMB, start:%d, end:%d, duration:%d\n", num_bytes_/(1024*1024), ts1, ts2, ts2-ts1);
   53       printf("cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:%zuMB, duration:%d\n", num_bytes_/(1024*1024), ts2-ts1);
   54
   55       // measuring initialization
   56       ts1 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
>> 57       init<<<1,1>>>(dptr, num_bytes_);
   58       ts2 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
   59       myfile<<"initialization, "<<num_bytes_/(1024*1024)<<","<<ts1<<","<<ts2<<","<<ts2-ts1<<"\n";
   60       //printf("init, memory_size:%zuMB, start:%d, end:%d, duration:%d\n", num_bytes_/(1024*1024), ts1, ts2, ts2-ts1);
   61       printf("init, memory_size:%zuMB, duration:%d\n", num_bytes_/(1024*1024), ts2-ts1);
   62
   63       // measuring cudaFree
   64       ts1 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
>> 65       cudaFree(dptr);
   66       ts2 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
   67       myfile<<"cudaFree, "<<num_bytes_/(1024*1024)<<","<<ts1<<","<<ts2<<","<<ts2-ts1<<"\n";
   68       //printf("cudaFree, memory_size:%zuMB, start:%d, end:%d, duration:%d\n", num_bytes_/(1024*1024), ts1, ts2, ts2-ts1);
   69       printf("cudaFree, memory_size:%zuMB, duration:%d\n", num_bytes_/(1024*1024), ts2-ts1);
   70       sleep(1);
   71       printf("\n");
   72     }
   73   }
   74   myfile.close();
   75   return 1;
   76 }
```

Results

```
cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:1MB, duration:360
init, memory_size:1MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:1MB, **duration:2**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:2MB, duration:1
init, memory_size:2MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:2MB, **duration:4**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:4MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:4MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:4MB, **duration:9**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:8MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:8MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:8MB, **duration:18**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:16MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:16MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:16MB, **duration:34**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:32MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:32MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:32MB, **duration:69**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:64MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:64MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:64MB, **duration:132**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:128MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:128MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:128MB, **duration:241**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:256MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:256MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:256MB, **duration:476**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:512MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:512MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:512MB, **duration:984**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:1024MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:1024MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:1024MB, **duration:1910**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:2048MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:2048MB, duration:1
cudaFree, memory_size:2048MB, **duration:3830**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:4096MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:4096MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:4096MB, **duration:7715**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:8192MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:8192MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:8192MB, **duration:0**

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:16384MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:16384MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:16384MB, **duration:0**
```

- weird thing is that 8192MB and 16384MB shows less than 0ms not only for cudaManagedMalloc and init but also for cudaFree....

Please enlighten me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does cudaFree have such a huge overhead?

It doesn't. The timing method you are using is incorrect and the time you attributed to `cudaFree` comes from prior asynchronous operations

> Does it fill whole memory region with zero for security issue?

No

> Or any other critical path it walks through?

No, except it requires the device to be idle, which it is not in your case.

Let's fix the most obvious problem with you code:

```
  // measuring initialization
  ts1 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
  init<<<1,1>>>(dptr, num_bytes_);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // Wait until the GPU is idle
  ts2 = getTimeDiff(baseTime);
```

And then run your experiment:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o fliestime fliestime.cu 

$ ./fliestime 
sizeof(size_t): 8
sizeof(unsigned int): 4
sizeof(int): 4
sizeof(long): 8
cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:1MB, duration:102
init, memory_size:1MB, duration:2
cudaFree, memory_size:1MB, duration:1

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:2MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:2MB, duration:5
cudaFree, memory_size:2MB, duration:0

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:4MB, duration:1
init, memory_size:4MB, duration:8
cudaFree, memory_size:4MB, duration:0

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:8MB, duration:1
init, memory_size:8MB, duration:17
cudaFree, memory_size:8MB, duration:1

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:16MB, duration:1
init, memory_size:16MB, duration:33
cudaFree, memory_size:16MB, duration:1

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:32MB, duration:3
init, memory_size:32MB, duration:65
cudaFree, memory_size:32MB, duration:2

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:64MB, duration:5
init, memory_size:64MB, duration:121
cudaFree, memory_size:64MB, duration:4

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:128MB, duration:9
init, memory_size:128MB, duration:219
cudaFree, memory_size:128MB, duration:8

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:256MB, duration:17
init, memory_size:256MB, duration:427
cudaFree, memory_size:256MB, duration:18

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:512MB, duration:34
init, memory_size:512MB, duration:854
cudaFree, memory_size:512MB, duration:35

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:1024MB, duration:67
init, memory_size:1024MB, duration:1709
cudaFree, memory_size:1024MB, duration:70

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:2048MB, duration:133
init, memory_size:2048MB, duration:3418
cudaFree, memory_size:2048MB, duration:141

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:4096MB, duration:786
init, memory_size:4096MB, duration:4
cudaFree, memory_size:4096MB, duration:0

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:8192MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:8192MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:8192MB, duration:0

cudaMallocManaged, memory_size:16384MB, duration:0
init, memory_size:16384MB, duration:0
cudaFree, memory_size:16384MB, duration:0
```

You can see that the time you have assumed is `cudaFree` is the time your completely serial `init` kernel takes to run. Both `cudaMallocManaged` and `cudaFree` do use more time as the allocations increase in size, but that isn't unreasonable IMHO.

> weird thing is that 8192MB and 16384MB shows less than 0ms not only for cudaManagedMalloc and init but also for cudaFree....

That is because nothing is running. If you employ correct [runtime error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/681865), you will see that everything is failing with out of memory runtime errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. I was unaware of "cudaDeviceSynchronize()" part. Now I see the root of overhead.. To make sure that I understand your answer correctly, so the host sends the kernels or cuda API call to GPU regardless of whether it is actually finished or not. And without explicit synchronization, there is no way for the host to know API or kernel are actually done.

Comment: Kernels are asycnhronous by default. Other APIs may block or be asynchronous, depending on the API. They are all documented. In this case cudaFree is not asychronous, so it blocks until the device is idle. And accumulates the wall clock time of the kernel running in the process.  CUDA has a facility called events which can be used to instrument individual operations or groups of operations for sychronization, callbacks, timing, etc if you need it

Comment: Thank you a lot again for your input. I see clearly what was going on behind. I guess I need to look up events part as well.